# how to update record ignore id in mybatis and postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

Now I am using mybatis to update PostgreSQL 13 record, I want to using user id to update apple purchase prouct id in user table, this is my code:

```
Users users = new Users();
users.setId(payTransactionRecord.getUserId());
users.setAppleIapProductId(productId);
```

I give the user entity id and product id, update product id by using user id. this is the update execute code using mybatis:

```
public int updateByPrimaryKey(Users user) {
        UsersExample example = new UsersExample();
        UsersExample.Criteria criteria = example.createCriteria();
        criteria.andIdEqualTo(user.getId());
        return userMapper.updateByExampleSelective(user,example);
    }
```

but the mybatis geneate the sql like this cause error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" can only be updated to DEFAULT
  Detail: Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
### The error may exist in class path resource [mybatis/mapper/dolphin/UsersMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.dolphin.soa.post.dao.UsersMapper.updateByExampleSelective-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE users SET id = ?, apple_iap_product_id = ? WHERE (id = ?)
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" can only be updated to DEFAULT
  Detail: Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" can only be updated to DEFAULT
  Detail: Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
```

what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement is wrongly defined. You stated, that you only want to update apple purchase product ID of a users entry. But in the statement it is tried to update the ID of the users entry itself as well.
The error message states that its value is always generated, therefore manual updates of values in the users ID column are not allowed.
Try removing the ID from the SET part and only apply it in the WHERE part.